# file upload not working in express js using ejs view engine

Tags: node.js, express

I have tried to do file upload in express js project. used ejs as default view engine.

file not uploaded to /uploads folder.

here is my code below.

in app.js file have imported required packages

in routes/index.js route file created route

```
router.get('/index',indexController.index);
router.post('/insertion',indexController.insertion);

module.exports = router;
```

in controllers/indexController.js

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:function(req,file,cb)
    {
        cb(null,'./../uploads');
    },

    filename:function(req,file,cb)
    {
        callback(null,file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage:storage}).single('resume');

exports.insertion = function(req,res)
{
    var file = req.files.resume;
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log('file uploaded successfully!');
        }
    });

    res.end();
}
```

in views/registration.ejs file

```
<form name="registration" action="/insertion" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Resume</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="resume" class="form-control" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

file uploading not working .. i need to upload the file under uploads folder which is created in root directory

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: not getting any error but file not moved

Comment: file upload successfully showing in console